# Springboot app works on embbeded tomcat but in external tomcat get 404

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I have a project on spring and when i run it on the embbeded tomcat it works so good
But the idea is put the project in a external server but when i create the war
and i deploy it in tomcat 8 i get 404 even if it is running

I have seen that the problem could be in the maven but i tried a lot of things that i saw
in other posts and i cant fix it

i dont knot what else i can do.

here is some of my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RD extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
        @Resource
     // FileStorageService storageService;
        
        FileStorageService storageService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RD.class, args);
    }
      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
          return builder.sources(RD.class);
      }
      @Override
      public void run(String... arg) throws Exception {
        storageService.deleteAll();
        storageService.init();
      }

}
```

my main class already has the serverlet extends i think that its not the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.r</groupId>
    <artifactId>RD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>RDrone</name>
    <description>Portal Web</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-validation</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
  
    </dependencies>

    <build>
     <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is my pom where i think that could be the problem

I tried to make some exlusion on the springgboot starter web dependecy but it doesnt work

Thats what i see that fix it in other project but not in mine

I dont know if could be something on my tomcat but i have tomcat 8 with java 1.8

Comment: What URL are you using to access the app when it's deployed as a WAR?

Answer (score 0):

I deployee spring boot restful app on wildfly what I do is create the class `ServletInitializer` .

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(FikerApplication.class);
    }

}
```

I hope this will give you the solution, if not comment me I will try to figure out .

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you have a separate class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` or you main class extends it.

Comment: I already have that class but i still have the problem